# Difference between cloning and deepcopy?

Tags: python, cloning, deep-copy

I've just started programming, and am working my way through "How to think like a Computer Scientist" for Python. I haven't had any problems until I came to an exercise in Chapter 9:

```
def add_column(matrix):

    """
    >>> m = [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
    >>> add_column(m)
    [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
    >>> n = [[3, 2], [5, 1], [4, 7]]
    >>> add_column(n)
    [[3, 2, 0], [5, 1, 0], [4, 7, 0]]
    >>> n
    [[3, 2], [5, 1], [4, 7]]
    """
```

The code should make the above doctest pass. I was getting stuck on the last test: getting the original list to stay unaffected. I looked up the solution, which is the following:

```
x = len(matrix)

matrix2 = [d[:] for d in matrix]
for z in range(x):
    matrix2[z] += [0]
return matrix2
```

My question is this: why can't the second line be:

```
matrix2 = matrix[:]
```

When this line is in place the original list gets edited to include the addition elements. The "How to be.." guide makes it sound like cloning creates a new list that can be edited without affecting the original list. If that were true, what's going on here? If I use:

```
matrix2 = copy.deepcopy(matrix)
```

Everything works fine, but I wasn't under the impression that cloning would fail...
any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Say you have nested lists, copying will only copy the references to those nested lists.

```
>>> a = [1]
>>> b = [2]
>>> c = [a, b]
>>> c
[[1], [2]]
>>> d = c[:]
>>> d
[[1], [2]]
>>> d[1].append(2)
>>> d
[[1], [2, 2]]
>>> c
[[1], [2, 2]]
```

As where, with `copy.deepcopy()`:

```
>>> d = copy.deepcopy(c)
>>> d[1].append(2)
>>> c
[[1], [2]]
>>> d
[[1], [2, 2]]
```

This is true of any mutable items. `copy.deepcopy()` will attempt to make sure that they are copied too.

It's also worth noting that using `d = c[:]` to copy a list isn't a very clear syntax anyway. A much better solution is `d = list(c)` (`list()` returns a new list from any iterable, including another list). Even more clear, obviously, is [`copy.copy()`](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html#copy.copy).

Comment: Thanks for the help- I think I understand at this point. Is there any reason why you would want to make discrete copies of a matrix but keep the nested lists within referring to the same object? I'm not far enough into the process to foresee how that would be anything other than confusing...

Comment: It's less a design decision, and more just a repercussion of how Python works. Whenever you assign in Python, you don't copy the object, you simply assign the variable as a reference to it. It wouldn't make sense to arbitrarily do otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, `matrix` contains other lists, so when you do `matrix[:]`, you are cloning `matrix`, which contains references to other lists. Those are not cloned too. So, when you edit these, they are still the same in the original `matrix` list. However, if you append an item to the copy (`matrix[:]`), it will not be appended to the original list.

To visualize this, you can use the `id` function which returns a unique number for each object: see [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#id).

```
a = [[1,2], [3,4], 5]
print 'id(a)', id(a)
print '>>', [id(i) for i in a]

not_deep = a[:]
# Notice that the ids of a and not_deep are different, so it's not the same list
print 'id(not_deep)', id(not_deep)
# but the lists inside of it have the same id, because they were not cloned!
print '>>', [id(i) for i in not_deep]

# Just to prove that a and not_deep are two different lists
not_deep.append([6, 7])
print 'a items:', len(a), 'not_deep items:', len(not_deep)

import copy
deep = copy.deepcopy(a)
# Again, a different list
print 'id(deep)', id(deep)
# And this time also all the nested list (and all mutable objects too, not shown here)
# Notice the different ids
print '>>', [id(i) for i in deep]
```

And the output:

```
id(a) 36169160
>> [36168904L, 35564872L, 31578344L]
id(not_deep) 35651784
>> [36168904L, 35564872L, 31578344L]
a items: 3 not_deep items: 4
id(deep) 36169864
>> [36168776L, 36209544L, 31578344L]
```

Comment: I THINK I understand...so if "matrix" didn't include nested lists, I'd be okay because there'd only be one level to clone? And that's why deepcopy works-- it's copying every level down, even the nested lists...   I guess "How to be..." was trying to teach the most basic concepts in their entirety before going on to more sensible approaches, but it just ended up confusing me.    Thanks!